# Why is `from_now` wrong when called on a Fixnum?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, yaml, erb

I need to store some time periods in a yaml file, like this:

```
test:
testing: <%= 1.month %>
```

I grab the data in an initializer like this:

```
Class::TIMES = YAML.load(ERB.new(File.new(Rails.root.join('config', 'times.yml')).read).result)
```

So far so good. But the times I get from this are always off by a day; testing shows this. For example:

```
<Tue, 06 Mar 2012> expected but was <Wed, 07 Mar 2012>.
```

The test line:

```
assert_equal 1.month.from_now.to_date, @object.finished_at.to_date
```

Elsewhere, @object's finished_at is set like this:

```
# duration is from the YAML file
self.finished_at = duration.from_now
```

It always seems to be off by a day, no matter what time period I put in the YAML file. Why does this happen?

EDIT: This seems to be an issue with Fixnums and `from_now`:

```
> 1.month.from_now
 => Tue, 06 Mar 2012 21:05:00 UTC +00:00 

> 1.month.to_i.from_now
 => Wed, 07 Mar 2012 21:05:05 UTC +00:00
```

Comment: What time-zone are you using to test? You should be using UTC for all values internally and rendering to a user's local time-zone for display purposes.

Comment: They're all UTC. But I think I've found the real issue. I've edited my question appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you convert 1.month to an integer it arbitrary sets the duration getting passed into from_now to 2592000 seconds i.e 30 days regardless of what month it is.

I ran into this issue once before. Check out the documentation for the [Data and Time Helper Methods](http://as.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Numeric/Time.html#M000334) .

> While these methods provide precise calculation when used as in the
>   examples above(".. 1.month.from_now .."), care should be taken to note
>   that this is not true if  the result of `months’,`years’, etc is
>   converted before use